# How to add bootstrap moadal in reactJs calendar?

Tags: reactjs

I am working in MERN project where i want to add a bootstarp modal in react calendar. i want that, if any any user clicks on any date a modal should popup. but i don't know how to proceed. please suggest me some good way to achieve this.

**my code**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Calendar from 'react-calendar'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';
import moment from 'moment'

export default function AddMember() {
    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date())
    const changeDate = (e) => {
        setDateState(e)
       
    }


    return (
        <>
        
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8'>
                        <Calendar 
                            value={dateState}
                            onChange={changeDate}
                        />
                       
                        <p>Current selected date is <b>{moment(dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}</b> </p>
                   
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve by setting modal state in your `changeDate` function like this.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Calendar from 'react-calendar'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css';
import moment from 'moment'

// import Modal from react-bootrap
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';

export default function AddMember() {
    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date())
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false)
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true)
    
    const changeDate = (e) => {
        setDateState(e)
        handleShow()
    }

    return (
        <>
        
            <div className='container mt-5'>
                <div className='row'>
                    <div className='col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8'>
                        <Calendar 
                            value={dateState}
                            onChange={changeDate}
                        />
                        <p>Current selected date is <b>   {moment(dateState).format('MMMM Do YYYY')}</b> </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
               // your modal content goes here
          </Modal>
        </>
    )
}
```

Now whenever user clicks or select a date a modal will popup. Happy coding :-)